# Comparing fields when a field has data in between 2 characters that match the field being compared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have code that looks like this:

```
left outer join 
   gme_batch_header bh 
on 
   substr(ln.lot_number,instr(ln.lot_number,'(') + 1, 
   instr(ln.lot_number,')') - instr(ln.lot_number,'(') - 1) 
   = 
   bh.batch_no
```

It works fine, but I have come across a few lot numbers that have two sections of strings that are between parenthesis. How would I compare what is between the second set of parenthesis? Here is an example of the data in the lot number field:

```
E142059-307-SCRAP-(74055)
```

This one works with the code,

```
58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)
```

This one tries comparing SCRAP with the batch no, which isn't correct. It needs to be the 61448.

The result is always the last item in parenthesis.

Comment: can you use like? `left outer join gme_batch_header bh 
on ln.lot_number LIKE '%(' + bh.batch_no + ')%'`

Comment: If the number is always at the end of the string, you could use `RIGHT(ln.lot_number, instr(reverse(ln.lot_number), '('))` to isolate it.

Comment: I am using Oracle/PLSQL, it does not like the RIGHT function.

Comment: And yes the number is always at the end of the lot number.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, I actually got it to work with this code:

```
substr(ln.lot_number,instr(ln.lot_number,'(',-1) + 1, instr(ln.lot_number,')',-1) - instr(ln.lot_number,'(',-1) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL2005+, and it is always the last occurrence you want, then I would suggest finding the last instance of a ( in your query and substring to there. To get the last instance you could use something like:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(lot_number),0,CHARINDEX('(',REVERSE(lot_number))))
```

Comment: I am using Oracle/PLSQL, it does not like the CHARINDEX function.

Comment: And yes the number is always at the end of the lot number.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Oracle supports regular expressions try this:

```
substr(regexp_substr(ln.lot_number,'[0-9]+\)$'),1,length(regexp_substr(ln.lot_number,'[0-9]+\)$'))-1)
```

Explanation:

`regexp_substr(scrap_row,'[0-9]+\)$' ==> find me just numbers in the string that ends in ).` This returns the numbers but it includes the closing parenthesis.

To remove the closing parenthsis, just send it through substring and extract first number through the length of the number stopping at 1 character from the end of the string.

Query for analysis:

```
with scrap
as (select '58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)' as scrap_row from dual)
select scrap_row, 
       regexp_substr(scrap_row,'[0-9]+\)$')            as  regex_substring,
       length(regexp_substr(scrap_row,'[0-9]+\)$'))    as  length_regex_substring,
       substr(regexp_substr(scrap_row,'[0-9]+\)$'),1,length(regexp_substr(scrap_row,'[0-9]+\)$'))-1) as regex_sans_parenthesis
from scrap
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 11g, this will do it pretty simply by using the subgroup argument of regexp_substr() and constructing the regex appropriately:

```
SQL> with tbl(data) as
    (
      select 'E142059-307-SCRAP-(74055)' from dual
      union
      select '58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)' from dual
    )
    select data from tbl
    where regexp_substr(data, '\((\d+)\)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
      = '61448';

DATA
------------------------------
58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)
```

The regular expression can be read as:

```
\(   - Search for a literal left paren
(    - Start a remembered subgroup
\d+  - followed by 1 more more digits
)    - End remembered subgroup
\)   - followed by a literal right paren
$    - at the end of the line.
```

The regexp_substr function arguments are:

```
Source        - the source string
Pattern       - The regex pattern to look for
position      - Position in the string to start looking for the pattern
occurrence    - If the pattern occurs multiple times, which occurrence you want
match_params  - See the docs, not used here
subexpression - which subexpression to use (the remembered group)
```

So in English, look for a series of 1 or more digits surrounded by parens, where it occurs at the end of the line and save the digit part only to use to compare.  IMHO a lot easier to follow/maintain than nested instr(), substr().

For re-useability, make a function called get_last_number_in_parens() that contains this code and uses an argument of the string to search.  This way that logic is encapsulated and can be re-used by folks that may not be so comfortable with regular expressions, but can benefit from the power!  One place to maintain code too.  Then call like this:

```
select data from tbl
where get_last_number_in_parens(data) = '61448';
```

How easy is that?!

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello you can check with this code. It works whaever the condition may be

SELECT SUBSTR('58LF-3-B-2-2-2-(61448)',instr('58LF-3-B-2-2-2-(61448)','(',-1)+1,LENGTH('58LF-3-B-2-2-2-(61448)')-instr('58LF-3-B-2-2-2-(61448)','(',-1)-1)
FROM dual;


SELECT SUBSTR('58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)',instr('58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)','(',-1)+1,LENGTH('58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)')-instr('58LF-3-B-2-2-2 (SCRAP)-(61448)','(',-1)-1)
FROM dual;

Output
==================================
61448
==================================
```